# Binomial coefficient identity found in Apéry's theorem

Tags: proof-explanation, riemann-zeta

In Apéry's proof of the irrationality of $\zeta(3)$, while proving the formula for the fast-converging series $\zeta(3)=\frac{5}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{ (-1)^{k-1}} {k^{3}\binom {2k}{k}}}$ there is the following identity:

$$
\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!^2}{n^2(n^2-1^2)\ldots(n^2-(n-1)^2)} = \frac{2(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}},
$$

for positive integer $n>0$. I can't for the life of me figure out how to prove this is true. By eliminating on both sides the $(-1)^{n-1}$ in the numerator and the $n^2$ in the denominator, we are left with:

$$
\frac{(n-1)!^2}{(n^2-1^2)\ldots(n^2-(n-1)^2)} = \frac{2}{ \binom{2n}{n}}.
$$

But this already seems absurd! Using Wolfram Alpha [shows](http://((n-1)!%5E2/(sum%20(n%5E2-r%5E2)r=1%20to%20n-1))%20-%20(2/(2n%20choose%20n))) that LHS-RHS is not zero, therefore the "identity" does not hold.

What am I missing? Note that I am using [Van der Poorten's paper](http://pracownicy.uksw.edu.pl/mwolf/Poorten_MI_195_0.pdf) to understand Apéry's proof. The identity in question can be seen on the page labelled "**197**", on the bottom of the left column.

Comment: Your link to Wolfram Alpha does not work. A slight restatement of the identity works fine in Mathematica $\frac{((n-1)!)^2}{\prod _{k=1}^{n-1} \left(n^2-k^2\right)}=\frac{2}{\binom{2 n}{n}}$

Comment: $n^2 - k^2 = \left(n-k\right) \left(n+k\right)$. The $n-k$ factors cancel one of the two $\left(n-1\right)!$s in the numerator. What remains is $\dfrac{\left(n-1\right)!}{\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)\cdots\left(2n-1\right)} = 2\cdot \dfrac{n!}{\left(n+1\right)\left(n+2\right)\cdots\left(2n-1\right)\left(2n\right)} = 2/\dbinom{2n}{n}$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you, post this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @JamesArathoon Indeed, somehow the link got broken. I had the same formula as you, the best explanation is that I mistyped something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each integer $k$, we have $n^2 - k^2 = \left(n-k\right) \left(n+k\right)$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(n^2-k^2\right) &= \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(\left(n-k\right) \left(n+k\right)\right) = \underbrace{\left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(n-k\right) \right)}_{=\left(n-1\right)!} \underbrace{\left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(n+k\right)\right)}_{= \left(2n-1\right) \left(2n-2\right) \cdots \left(n+1\right)} \\
&= \left(n-1\right)! \left( \left(2n-1\right) \left(2n-2\right) \cdots \left(n+1\right) \right) .
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(n^2-k^2\right)}{\left(n-1\right)!^2}
 &= \dfrac{\left(n-1\right)! \left( \left(2n-1\right) \left(2n-2\right) \cdots \left(n+1\right) \right)}{\left(n-1\right)!^2} \\
 &= \dfrac{\left(2n-1\right) \left(2n-2\right) \cdots \left(n+1\right) }{\left(n-1\right)!} \\
 &= \dfrac{\left(2n\right) \cdot \left( \left(2n-1\right) \left(2n-2\right) \cdots \left(n+1\right) \right)}{\left(2n\right) \cdot \left(n-1\right)!} \\
 &= \dfrac{\left(2n\right) \left(2n-1\right) \left(2n-2\right) \cdots \left(n+1\right) }{2 n \cdot \left(n-1\right)!} \\
 &= \dfrac{\left(2n\right) \left(2n-1\right) \left(2n-2\right) \cdots \left(n+1\right) }{2 n!}
 \qquad \left(\text{since } n \cdot \left(n-1\right)! = n! \right) \\
 &= \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot \underbrace{\dfrac{\left(2n\right) \left(2n-1\right) \left(2n-2\right) \cdots \left(n+1\right) }{n!}}_{\substack{=\dbinom{2n}{n}\\ \text{(by the definition of }\dbinom{2n}{n}\text{)}}} \\
 &= \dfrac{1}{2} \dbinom{2n}{n}.
\end{align*}
Taking the reciprocal of both sides, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\left(n-1\right)!^2}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} \left(n^2-k^2\right)}
= \dfrac{2}{\dbinom{2n}{n}} .
\end{align*}
In other words,
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\left(n-1\right)!^2}{\left(n^2-1^2\right)\left(n^2-2^2\right)\cdots\left(n^2-\left(n-1\right)^2\right)}
= \dfrac{2}{\dbinom{2n}{n}} .
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for the precise explanation!